# NGRX, Rxjs: what is the better solution for this case? Observable in Action?

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngrx

In my  application, I have a case as following, I want to know how to do it in a better way:

```
// the effects function
this.user$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(UserActions.FETCH_USER),
  switchMap((_) => {
    return userService.getUser().pipe(
      map((res) => {
        return new UserActions.FetchUserSuccess(this.transformUserResData(res));
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        return observableOf(new UserActions.FetchUserFail());
      })
    );
  })
);
```

this is a simple effect function, the only point need to mention is for the `success` case, before passing the response data to the `FetchUserSuccess` function as payload. I need to transform it. And the transform function is as following:

```
  private transformUserResData(users: User[]): UserInfo[] {
    let groupIDNames: Array<IdNameMap>;
    this.groupStoreService.groupIDNames$.subscribe((res) => {
      groupIDNames = res; // array of {Id: "id", Name: "name"} object
    })
    return users.map((each) => {
      return {
        id: each.id,
        title: each.title,
        category: each.category, 
        groupName: groupIDNames.find(current => current.Id === each.groupID).Name
      };
    })       
  }
```

as you can see, the original transform data is array of user, and in each user there is a property named `gruopID`, which simply means the user belongs to which group.

And the transform function's purpose is map `groupID` to `groupName`, I want to add the group name information into the user object. Clear target, right?

And tricky point is here, the group id and name mapping data is an Observable. In fact it's the state values selected from NGRX store with `store.select` method as the `this.groupStoreService.groupIDNames$` goes.

So my current solution is posted here,  you can see I subscribe to the Observable and get the data as `groupIDNames`. And use it in the later parsing.

This can work, since the return value `this.groupStoreService.groupIDNames$` from `store.select` is `SubjectBehavior` type (this point is confirmed in my another post), so the subject callback function is sync.

It worked, but I know it's not best practice to do this. So I want to know how to improve it in another way.

I thought use the following method:

```
  private transformUserResData(users: User[]): Observable<UserInfo[]> {
    this.groupStoreService.groupIDNames$
       .pipe(map((groupIDNames) => {
          return users.map((each) => {
            return {
              id: each.id,
              title: each.title,
              category: each.category, 
              groupName: groupIDNames.find(current => current.Id === each.groupID).Name
           };
         })  
      }))     
  }
```

But in this way, the transform function will return Observable, and the Observable will be passed to redux action. I don't know it's best practice for redux.

If any other smarter solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your code a bit more reactively by composing your ngrx store observable with API response like this:

```
// the effects function
    this.user$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(UserActions.FETCH_USER),
      switchMap((_) => {
        return userService.getUser()
                         .pipe(
                                //lets transform the data
                                mergeMap((users: User[]) => {
                                  return this.groupStoreService.groupIDNames$
                                             .pipe(
                                               map((groupIDNames: Array<IdNameMap>) => {
                                                  return users.map((each) => {
                                                    return {
                                                      id: each.id,
                                                      title: each.title,
                                                      category: each.category, 
                                                      groupName: groupIDNames.find(current => current.Id === each.groupID).Name
                                                    };
                                                  });
                                               })
                                             );
                                }),
                                map((userInfos: UserInfo[]) => {
                                  return new UserActions.FetchUserSuccess(userInfos);
                                }),
                                catchError(() => {
                                  return observableOf(new UserActions.FetchUserFail());
                                })
                          );
      })
    );
```

If you want to avoid nesting of the operators, you can also write like this:

```
// the effects function
    this.user$ = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(UserActions.FETCH_USER),
      switchMap((_) => {
        return userService.getUser()
                         .pipe(
                                mergeMap((users: User[]) => {
                                  return combineLatest(of(users), this.groupStoreService.groupIDNames$.pipe(take(1)));
                                }),
                                map(([users, groupIDNames]) => {
                                  //project [map] your users to userInfo
                                  const userInfos = users.map((each) => {
                                                                return {
                                                                  id: each.id,
                                                                  title: each.title,
                                                                  category: each.category, 
                                                                  groupName: groupIDNames.find(current => current.Id === each.groupID).Name
                                                                };
                                                              });
                                  return new UserActions.FetchUserSuccess(userInfos);

                                }),                                
                                catchError(() => {
                                  return observableOf(new UserActions.FetchUserFail());
                                })
                          );
      })
    );
```